# Understand the Hyperbolic space

Tags: differential-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

I've been trying to find the expression for the metric of the hyperbolic n-space, $\mathbb H^n$.
For $n=2$ I've found (e.g. [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_metric)) that $$ds^2=\frac{dx^2+dy^2}{y^2}.$$
But for $n>2$ I can't seem to find the expression for the metric...

Can anyone help me with this?

Also, on a related question, If I have a scalar field that obeys to the Laplace equation in $\mathbb H^2$, I get that the solution is the same as if I've written the Lapace equation in $\mathbb R^2$...that came as a surprise for me...Why does that happen? (I'm trying to have some understanding of the Hyperbolic space.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Notes by Manfred Stoll](http://www.math.sc.edu/people/faculty/stoll/hyperbolic.pdf) look like a perfect match for your question: both the hyperbolic space (2.3) and harmonic functions on it (Chapters 3-4) are introduced from scratch. For the record, the metric on $\mathbb H^n$ is 
$ds^2 = \frac{dx^2}{x_n^2}$ where $dx^2$ is the Euclidean metric.

In dimension $2$ (**only**) the hyperbolic and Euclidean harmonic functions indeed coincide: see formulas (3.2) and the (yet unfinished) section 3.4. One might wonder if this is a feature or a bug. One of possible explanations is that hyperbolic isometries are conformal maps, and conformality is related to the Laplace equation only in dimension $2$. (In dimensions $n\ge 3$ conformal maps are related to the non-linear $n$-Laplace equation.)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and the detailed info of the reference.